# My HP laptop 'hidden' numpad does not output numbers when numlk is on

Tags: windows, laptop, keyboard

Like many laptops, my HP Elitebook 840 G3 laptop has an embedded numeric keypad, which can be accessed using the <kbd>fn</kbd> modifier key. So, when I press <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> it actually outputs "2" instead of "k".

**Problem:** 
Since a couple of days however, it doesn't output the numbers anymore. Instead they rather acts as navigation keys (arrow left, right, up, down, ...).
Turning on "num lock" using the embedded <kbd>numlk</kbd> key (i.e. pressing <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f12</kbd>) *permanently* turns on the embedded numeric keys (as mentioned in the user manual), but this is not what I want either.

**Question:**
How can I make the embedded numeric keypad output numbers again when using the <kbd>fn</kbd> modifier key?
I am running Windows 10.

[image: Elitebook keyboard from user manual]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Since I bumped into this issue for the 2nd time and it took me again a long time to figure out the solution, posting the answer to superuser)*

**Short answer**

Turn on the NumLock feature using the Windows on-screen keyboard, rather than using the <kbd>numlk</kbd> key on the physical laptop keyboard.

**Detailed answer**

1. Turn on the on-screen keyboard of Windows 10 (type flag key and then `on-screen')
   [image: Start - on-screen result]
2. In the on-screen keyboard, click the <kbd>Options</kbd> key
   [image: Options key]
3. In the dialog box that appears, select "Turn on numeric keypad" and click <kbd>OK</kbd>
   [image: Dialog box]
4. Then, on the on-screen keyboard, click the <kbd>NumLock</kbd> key, to turn on the "num lock" feature. As a result, the LED of the <kbd>numlk</kbd> on the laptop's physical keyboard will be on.
   [image: On-screen NumLock key]
5. Close the on-screen keyboard.

While this will turn on the LED of the <kbd>numlk</kbd> on the laptop's keyboard - just like it would when you would have turned it on by physically pressing <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>numlk</kbd> - the effect is different! 
Now the embedded numeric keys are not permanently on, but only when you use the <kbd>fn</kbd> modifier key.

Comment: What strange behavior. I never would have thought to look at on-screen kbd options for controlling how the real keyboard/keypad works. But it behaves as you describe here (win 10 10.0.19044). I understand why one might want to toggle the number pad for the on-screen kbd.  But why would one ever want the physical NumLk key to NOT be the way to toggle the numeric keypad?